# iOS: Navigation Bar not showing up on manual segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the following setup

> -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller A -> View Controller B

B has some left and right navigation items which show up in this sequence

I have another flow where

> -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller A  -> View Controller C -> View Controller B

In `ViewController` C, when a save button is sliced, I manually trigger the segue to show View B. But, in this scenario, the navigation bar does not show up.

If I embed controller B in a navigation controller, then in the prepareFor Segue of Controller C, I cannot refer this as the destination. How do I fix this?

I am putting in some screen shots of the settings below:

This is the nav bar in A
[image]

The segue from A->B. This is triggered by selecting a row in a table View
[image]

This is how the nav bar in B looks when triggered from A
[image]

The segue from A->C
[image]

This is the nav bar in C
[image]

The segue from C->B
[image]

From C to B, I am triggering the segue as below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueGroupView", sender: self)
        })
```

On this trigger, the nav bar in B is not appearing

Comment: you need to show a little bit about how you wrote your code to push your view controller or settings in storyboard if you are using it. this way your can give us more information to answer your issue.

Comment: I fixed it by embedding the target (B) in a navigation controller. In prepareForSegue, I get the destination of the navigation controller using NavigationController.topViewController. Then I can set the necessary parameters.